# How i get authorization for google drive with an existing access token in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, google-drive-api, access-token

Hello i need get authorization for read and write in google drive from objective C, already i have the access token.

With Google APIs Client Library for Java i can get atorization with my existing access token, like code follow:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new  GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
Plus plus = new Plus.builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)
.setApplicationName("Google-PlusSample/1.0")
.build();
```

somebody know if in objective C it is possible???

or is necesary that i do all process for the request authorization ????(https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/auth).

Also i would like know if is possible create, update or delete files in google drive but using REST Requests????, thank you.

regards.

Comment: Access tokens are short lived. You shouldn't be using an existing one. If you've already authenticated you should use a [refresh token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#refresh) to keep access.

Comment: You can find examples here: https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client